# Do you want hats?

Tags: discussion

## Update *(29/11/13)*:

We will have hats. For those who don't want to participate, there will be an option  in the site footer to disable these.

---

For a while now StackExchange has had a little winter themed event in December for sites to participate in called [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/).

[image]

Basically, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (similar to badges).

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

From previous years:

- Users had their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
- Individual users who didn’t want to participate, didn’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat had an "I hate hats" option available..
- The only visual change to the site itself was the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

This is totally optional. Should we take part in this? Instead of mass responses, just vote on either of the answers below. We have until Dec 1st to reply, so in a week or so, the answer with the most votes will be the one we go with.

Comment: Sounds like fun! xD

Comment: What is this, TF2? Count me in!

Comment: Oh trust me, they are tons of fun :)

Comment: Wait, are we supposed to downvote answers too or just upvote?

Comment: @WChargin Either goes, it's the one with the most votes that will be chosen.

Comment: @WChargin Do you want to vote once or twice? ;)

Comment: I just signed up the site.

Comment: @DantheMan I submitted a reply days ago. See the update. ;)

Comment: @iKlsR Hah. Ok. I just got the email yesterday.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, give us all the glorious hats.

Answer (score -3):

No, keep the site hat free please.